# progress bar in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Progress Bar in Angular 2, Already I tried this code but getting error someone please help to overcome this issue

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.step = 1; 
    $scope.next = function(){
              
    $scope.step++;
   
       
   
      };   
    }

function MyCtrl1($scope) {
    $scope.step1 = 10;
        };
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{step}} <br>

    <progress value="{{step*1}}" max="10"></progress> 
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">{{step1}} <br>
    <a ng-click="next()">next</a> 
    
</div>
```

Comment: please specify whether you want in Angular 1 or Angular 2

Comment: you are using angular js not angular